# SQL JSON_QUERY constructing json path using values from a column and receiving error

Tags: angular, sql, sql-server, t-sql, nullable

For the following query, I receive the error when running it:

> The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(sr.Options, CONCAT('$[', sr.OptionId,']')
FROM Survey as sr
```

The column 'Options' contains JSON similar to this: [{"Id":1, "Text": "Yes"},{"Id":2, "Text": "No"}] and 'OptionId' relates to the index of one of these options which I want to return, but is nullable and in that case, I don't care what it returns. 'Options' will also sometimes be an empty array '[]' but in that case 'OptionId' is always NULL.

This is being run against SQL Server 13.0.4001

I attempted various things on argument 2 of JSON_QUERY such as using a case statement to only use sr.OptionId when it is not null, trying to convert the type, and a where statement on the entire query to filter out null.

Comment: you can't use expressions in JSON_QUERY argument in your sql server version, only constants, like: '$[0]', '$[1]'. You can use OPENJSON to get the dynamic array value

Comment: thisn seems to work just fine in the last version https://dbfiddle.uk/HpYtQhsO

Comment: Are you taking into account the [JSON_QUERY() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) where it says, _In SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a variable as the value of path._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a different statement using `OPENJSON()` with default schema and an additional `APPLY` operator. The result from the `OPENJSON()` call is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`. In your case the `key` column contains the index of the element in the specified JSON array and the `value` column contains a JSON object.

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Survey
FROM (VALUES
   (0, '[{"Id":1,"Text":"Yes"},{"Id":2,"Text":"No"}]'), 
   (1, NULL),
   (NULL, '[]') 
) v (OptionId, Options)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Survey sr
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT [value] AS OptionJson
   FROM OPENJSON(sr.Options)
   WHERE sr.OptionID = CONVERT(int, [key])
) oa
```

As an additional note, as @AlwaysLearning already commented, the reason for the error is that using a variable as the value of path in the `JSON_QUERY()` is supported in SQL Server 2017+. For these versions, you may use the following statement:

```
SELECT 
   sr.OptionId,
   sr.Options,
   CASE 
      WHEN sr.OptionId IS NOT NULL THEN JSON_QUERY(sr.Options, CONCAT('$[', sr.OptionId, ']')) 
   END AS OptionJson
FROM Survey sr
```